# Create Increment Counter Trigger in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, database-trigger

I Would like to ask how to create a specific counter every row in trigger if i inserted data on the table

For Example, this is a result in which there are 5 data in every row  has 0 counter

Table *Animal*

```
Animal Counter 
Zebra 0 
Zebra 0 
Zebra 0 
Zebra 0 
Zebra 0
```

When I run a job using tMap, i want the final result like this

Table *Animal*: Final Results

```
Animal Counter
Zebra 0
Zebra 0
Zebra 0
Zebra 0
Zebra 0
Zebra 1
Zebra 1
Zebra 1
Zebra 1
Zebra 1
```

Every time i insert data, the field on counter always increment by one and data always inserted

Regards

Comment: This question is unclear. What is the condition that causes the counter to increase? Or should every new insert use a new count, no matter what is inserted?

Comment: Maybe there is here a modelisation problem. Why don't you build another table 'insertion' and link it to your table animal? Come to think of it : why don't you put a table 'animal_type', a table 'insertion' and between them you can put an associated table that will link both the previous table. With this last technic you will limit the double values in this animal column of yours.